# How to export VMData from azure across multiple subscriptions

Tags: azure, powershell, virtual-machine, subscription

I have been able to export VMData from a single azure subscription using the code below.

```
$VMs = Get-AzVM
$vmOutput = $VMs | ForEach-Object { 
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        "VM Name" = $_.Name
    "VM Profile" = $_.HardwareProfile.VmSize
        "VM Type" = $_.StorageProfile.osDisk.osType
        "VM Location" = $_.Location
        "VM Resource Group Name" = $_.ResourceGroupName -join ','
    }
}
$vmOutput | export-csv C:\Azure\VMdata.csv -delimiter ";" -force -notypeinformation
```

However, when using the code below to try and extract from across multiple subscriptions and get no results.

```
$azuresubs = Get-AzSubscription
$azureSubs.foreach{
    Select-AzSubscription $_
$VMs = Get-AzVM
$vmOutput = $VMs | ForEach-Object { 
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        "VM Name" = $_.Name
    "VM Profile" = $_.HardwareProfile.VmSize
        "VM Type" = $_.StorageProfile.osDisk.osType
        "VM Location" = $_.Location
        "VM Resource Group Name" = $_.ResourceGroupName -join ','
        }
    }
}
$vmOutput | export-csv C:\Azure\VMdata.csv -delimiter ";" -force -notypeinformation
```

Being new to powershell, I'm sure the syntax above is incorrect so any assistance would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think what happens here is you overwrite your variable on each pass (and last pass happens to have no vms). so you need to append to it, not overwrite it. define it before loop:

```
$vmOutput = @()
```

and then append to it inside the loop

```
$vmOutput += $Vms | bla-bla-bla
```

final:

```
$vmOutput = @()
$azuresubs = Get-AzSubscription
$azureSubs.foreach{
    Select-AzSubscription $_
    $VMs = Get-AzVM
    $vmOutput += $VMs | ForEach-Object { 
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        xxx
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As `+=`rebuilds the whole array every time, I'd assign directly `$vmOutput = $azureSubs.foreach{...`

Comment: you have to make sure nothing else returns in this case, because `Select-AzSubscription $_` this returns, so you capture that as well. but given this is looping over resources in Azure, overhead for recreating array is minimal compared to (for example) time it takes to perform actual queries to Azure. Ideal solution would be to use ArrayList and its add method. @LotPings